# Javascript frameworks for writing own HTML builders

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create **my own** HTML (actually HTML5) editor (or say builder, designer etc).

Is there any Javascript frameworks for writing your own HTML editors? They should provide functionalities like dragging-dropping, resizing objects, inline text editing, font and color selection etc.. And it must be cross-browser.

My need is actually similar to what [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/) does in Eclipse. It is simply a framework that allows users to create their own editors in Eclipse. I will do the same thing in Web. I therefore need a Javascript framework for the same purpose of GEF.

Please, don't recommend me online web builders. My aim is coding the builder, not the site.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find a all-in-one framework which will give you all tools you need to do a wysiwyg HTML editor.

If your need is a javascript framework which will provide you all graphical components you need, try somthing like Dojo. http://dojotoolkit.org/